# SIFT in python 2.7.9 and opencv2 doesn't work

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, sift

I tried a simple program to implement sift

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('sheikha.jpg')
gray= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

sift = cv2.SIFT()
kp = sift.detect(gray,None)

img=cv2.drawKeypoints(gray,kp)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but am getting an error

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sift.py", line 7, in 
    sift = cv2.SIFT()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIFT'**

i tried replacing this line with sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

and still error

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sift.py", line 7, in 
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xfeatures2d'**

please help!

Comment: `xfeatures2d` is for OpenCV 3.0 and above. For other versions of OpenCV below it, you need to use [features2D](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/features2d/doc/features2d.html)

Comment: @JeruLuke still same error

Comment: You have to download the package `features2D` install it and then check it out

Comment: it already exist in my opencv folder @JeruLuke

Comment: No I meant `features2D` not `xfeatures2d`

Comment: @JeruLuke yes actually both features2d and xfeatures2d folders are there. Still error occurs :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your version of OpenCV. This Method is available for OpenCV 3.0 and above.

You can check the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/). It has [features2d](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/features2d/doc/features2d.html?highlight=features2d)